# Webscrapping using python

Tags: python

I have to extract whole table in csv from the give URL
https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/warning/#lang=en

I tried but I cannot extract with same column name because when I try to extract text it ignores all blank and I need exactly same table in csv format using Beautiful Soup and selenium

```py
from cgi import print_form
from cgitb import text
from lib2to3.pytree import type_repr
import time
from turtle import clear, title
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/warning/#lang=en'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
A = ['th']
def first_column(A, soup):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    k = 0
    for i in A:
        temp = []
        temp.extend(strong_tag.text for strong_tag in soup.find_all(i,attrs={'class' : ['contents-area contents-clickable warning-clickable','contents-clickable warning-clickable']}))
        temp = list(temp)
        df["{}".format(temp[0])] = temp[1:]
    
    df = df.drop_duplicates()
    return df

def remaining_data(soup):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in A:
        temp = []
        temp.extend(strong_tag.text for strong_tag in soup.find_all('tr'))
        temp = list(temp)
        df["{}".format(temp[3])] = temp[4:]
    
    df = df.drop_duplicates()
    return df

df = first_column(A, soup)
df2 = remaining_data(soup)
#df2.drop(df2.index[df2["HokkaidoHeavy Rain(Inundation)Heavy Rain(Landslide)FloodStormGaleHigh WaveStorm SurgeThunder StormDense FogDry Air"] == ""])
df2.reset_index()
df["Warnings"] = df2.loc[:]

warnings_list = ["Advisory", "Warning", "Emergency Warning"]
df["Final Warnings"] = "No Warnings"
for i in range(0, len(warnings_list)):
    for k in range(0, len(df)):
        if warnings_list[i] in df["Warnings"].loc[k]:
            df["Final Warnings"].loc[k] = warnings_list[i]
        # else:
        #     df["Final Warnings"] = ""
df = df.drop(columns = "Warnings")
df.columns = ["Locations","Alert Type"]
df.to_csv("Japan_Warning_alerts.csv")
```

Comment: please include the code snippet of what you have tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Kapil for the code
But The issue is that on this website table column names are changing sometimes there are 5 columns sometimes there are 6 
They are not constant so we can't put them in headers

Comment: okay, so what you can do is maybe extract the columns dynamically, the way i was extracting, it is able to get the headers at this line ```df.columns = df.iloc[1, :]``` so we can dynamically get the headers from here

Answer (score 1):

here you go, this divides up the file by region too

```
import datetime
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import pandas as pd

TABLE_HEADER = "Heavy Rain(Inundation),Heavy Rain(Landslide),Flood,StormGale,High Wave,Storm Surge,Thunder Storm,Dense Fog"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "drivers", "geckodriver.exe"))
driver.get("https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/warning/#lang=en")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until((EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.contents-wide-table-scroll"))))
tables = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="div.contents-wide-table-scroll")
df = pd.read_html(tables.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
driver.quit()

df = df[0]
df.columns = df.iloc[1, :]
df = df.iloc[2:, :]
df.to_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data", "data.csv"), index=False)


def save(current_table, name):
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data", f"{name}.csv"), "w") as write_file:
        write_file.writelines(current_table)


for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data")):
    current_table = [TABLE_HEADER]
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data", file), "r", encoding="utf-8") as read_file:
        for line in read_file.readlines():
            if TABLE_HEADER in line:
                name = line.split(",")[0]
                save(current_table, name)
                current_table = [TABLE_HEADER]
            else:
                current_table.append(line)
```